# How to implement impressions and impression tracking

Tags: php, analytics, impressions

I am building a dynamic website in plain php. The website is an eCommerce website where I wanted to get impressions of a single product. Please tell be how can I implement impressions for analytic of a products using pie charts or graphs.thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very broad and general question. You should search the web for more information before asking a question like this. This should help you:

https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=ecommerce%20analytics

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ecommerce

Comment: what about simple impressions ? product views and visits ?

Comment: Same answer. Please search and read linked documentation.